# What are the most complex languages to romanize (other than IPA)

Tags: romanization

While romanization often is a lossy transformation, it helps with pronunciation. I have looked at the romanizations for a few written languages and they are all easily romanizable. (Hebrew, Tibetan, Sanskrit, Pinyin, Vietnamese, Armenian, Arabic, Gothic, Old English, Danish, Norwegian, Japanese). I tried to pick languages that were different and had their own scripts. Some of the languages I haven't tried that have their own scripts are English (this would be hard because you have to know the spelling of each word individually it seems), French, Finnish, German, Yoruba, Igbo, Hausa, (a lot of languages, like African, Latin American, and Native American, are written in Latin script, so I could list many here), Telugu, Tamil, Korean, Mongolian, Russian, Georgian, Ancient Egyptian, etc..

Are there any languages that are particularly hard to romanize, or have particularly bad romanizations currently? Just want to make sure I'm not missing something, because the romanizations out there all so far seem pretty good.

I am mainly talking about written languages, because capturing all the IPA stuff requires much more than your typical romanization scheme can handle.

Comment: What is a good and bad Romanization? Which of the [many Russian romanization schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian) is good or bad? Note that the list in the article is hardly complete, mainly concerns only English schemes.

Comment: Good is that it accurately either maintains sound or letters or both, bad is it doesn't.

Comment: Maintains in which sense? Does novodévičij or novodevichy preserves those better or worse? Or makes them better apparent by changing the signs or not?

Comment: This question is on topic, shows basic research and is relatively original.  Instead of downvoting without explanation, I suggest improving it to be a bit more focused and objectively answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pinyin, Vietnamese, Danish and Norwegian are already romanized (written in a Latin-based script), the first example by definition (it's the now-standard romanization of Mandarin). You didn't mention French in your first list, which uses more diacritics that Norwegian, so are you really asking "how hard would it be to get rid of all of the diacritics as well". Norwegian is a snap: å=aa, æ=ae, ø=oe; nobody really needs é.

There are widely-adopted romanization schemes for writing a number of non-Latin based national languages, for example Ethiopic Semitic in general, (Standard) Arabic, Japanese, Mandarin. A well-known problem with pinyin is the lack of tone marks, but this is a problem with the practice of pinyin and not the system itself, which does provide tone marks. Otherwise, it is a good representation of how words are pronounced in Mandarin (there is, of course, no possible representation of "the letters"). However, it is not at all a representation of how e.g. Nantongese is pronounced. Japanese seems to pose a problem in how to romanize some Chinese characters, because they may have multiple pronunciations.

Moving to alphabets, abjads and so on, I don't think there are any romanization schemes which are significantly bad, as a method of transliterating. Romanized Khalkha Mongolian is misleading in terms of pronunciation, but so is the underlying Cyrillic spelling (too many people have made wrong phonological claims because they didn't understand the archaic nature of the Cyrillic spelling system). SE Asian languages seem to suffer somewhat from standardization problems so perhaps that is where you'll find the best candidate for "problem". Because there are reasonably well worked out conventions for Cyrillic romanization, that covers quite a number of languages. Perhaps there are problematic languages written with Perso-Arabic script, where this representation of [Talyshi romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talysh_language#Phonology_and_scripts) is less ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Generalising, the good Romanisations are 1:1 ie reversible, and the bad Romanisations are lossy or require not just a language model but a calibration to the transliterator's style, assuming it is even consistent.

The Serbo-Croatian Latin version is a well-known example of a good Romanisation that is also used and understood by laypeople.  It's still not fully 1:1 and not fully reversible.  It's also just a fundamentally easier conversion than some others, where 1:1ness between the two scripts is even less.

If we count the informal Romanisations - which exist for all major languages written in other alphabets like Russian, Chinese and Arabic and are actually the largest by volume - bad Romanisations are potentially infinite, so it's hard to list the bad ones.

One type that is relatively official and especially bad are double transliterations, for example Georgian or Armenian which was first transliterated to Russian Cyrillic and then to Latin.  It gets even worse if the Latin style chosen is inspired by, say, French.  For example `Խաչատուր Համբարձումյան - Хачатур Амбарцумян - Khatchatour Ambartsoumian`.

Maybe there are even triple transliterations, but no example occurs to me.

Comment: Can you provide any examples of 1:1 reversible/lossless romanizations? I only know of 2 (tibetan and maybe sanskrit) after looking at hundreds of languages (granted I only looked for romanizations for about 20 so far).

Comment: Not sure what you count as 1:1, but the examples in the table in httpss://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Georgian are close.  Using `’` is not as ambiguous like digraphs are.